# How to rename files with sequential numbers with bash?

Tags: bash, file, rename

I have 308,000 files located in the same directory, which are named using important information I would like to keep:

e.g.

```
"f_500_0.1_0.005_150_25.gen"
"f_500_0.1_0.005_150_26.gen"
"f_500_0.1_0.005_150_27.gen"
 [...]
"f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_25.gen"
"f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_26.gen"
"f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_27.gen"
```

I would like to rename all these files just by adding a number at the beginning of each filename, which will go from 1 to 12 sequentially until all 308,000 files have been assigned a number, like this:

```
# First 12 files:
"1_f_500_0.1_0.005_150_25.gen"
"2_f_500_0.1_0.005_150_26.gen"
[...]
"10_f_500_0.1_0.005_150_27.gen"
"11_f_500_0.1_0.005_150_28.gen"
"12_f_500_0.1_0.005_150_29.gen" 
# (and then again from 1 to 12 for the next 12 files:)  
"1_f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_25.gen"
"2_f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_26.gen"
[...]
"10_f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_27.gen"
"11_f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_28.gen"
"12_f_1000_0.1_0.005_150_29.gen" 
 # (and so on until all 308,000 files are renamed)
```

In the end, I just want to have grossly as many files with filename starting by "1_f...", than files with filename starting with "2_f..", and so on. How could I do that within my Unix shell? I am not fluent with bash.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Question: _ would like to split all these files into 12 groups of equivalent size and assign them a number (from 1 to 12), _ What do you mean, do you want to create 12 files with the content of all these files evenly spread over 12 files? Or do you want to split the content of each file into 12 files per file. Or do you want to .... . Sorry it is realy not clear!

Comment: I am sorry. I tried to simplify some parts of the question and add an example to make it clearer. I hope it is better now, I am not used to programming vocabulary. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple with a `for` loop in bash.

You can loop over all files in the directory by using output of `ls` command to `for` command. You need a variable which stores the index and you can update it in the loop.

```
export i=1
for f in $(ls)
do
   # Copy file to new location, safer than move in case you make a mistake
   cp $f ../new_directory/$i"_"$f -v

   # Increment
   let i=i+1
   # Reset if exceeds 12
   if [ $i -gt 12 ]
   then
      export i=1
   fi
done
```

You will have to be in the files directory, and will have to create `new_directory`. Best way to run is to save this as a script, and execute.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. I exported your code as a script to test it on a small subset of files and afterward, once I saw it worked, I modified it a bit to use `move` instead of `cp` (because all 308,000 files occupy >70Go and I could not duplicate them all). This was sure a good thing to first test it with `cp` though! Thanks again!

Comment: @Chrys you might want to have a look at `ln` to hardlink or softlink them. This way you keep the original file name and the new one.